# JqueryDatatable ajax post send data null to the action on project .net core 2.0

Tags: javascript, c#, datatables, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a problem with .net core 2.0 with datatables.

I am trying to make server side datatable.

Here is my javascript code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').dataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            paging: true,
            searching: true,
            lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50,100], [10, 25, 50,100]],
            pageLength: 10,
            destroy: true,
            ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("TableDatas", "Admin")",
                datatype: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: function (d) {
                    var postData = {
                        "request": d,
                        //Speacial Filter
                        "status" : "Something i am just trying."
                    };
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                },
                dataFilter: function (d) {
                    return d;
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    name: 'orderid',
                    data: 'orderid',
                    title: "Sipariş No",
                    sortable: false,
                    searchable: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'tmno',
                    data: "tMNo",
                    title: "TMNo",
                    sortable: false,
                    searchable: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'member',
                    data: "member",
                    title: "Müşteri",
                    sortable: false,
                    searchable: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'price',
                    data: "price",
                    title: "Tutar",
                    sortable: false,
                    searchable: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'date',
                    data: "date",
                    title: "Sipariş Tarihi",
                    sortable: false,
                    searchable: true,
                    render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return moment(data).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'status',
                    data: "status",
                    title: "Durum",
                    sortable: false,
                    searchable: true
                }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Here is the c# action . I am using DataTables nuget for it.

```
namespace DataTables.AspNet.Core
{
    public interface IDataTablesRequest
    {
        int Draw { get; }
        int Start { get; }
        int Length { get; }
        ISearch Search { get; }
        IEnumerable<IColumn> Columns { get; }
        IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalParameters { get; }
    }
}
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult TableDatas(IDataTablesRequest request,string status)
        {

            //There are some searchin paging codes...
            var response = DataTablesResponse.Create(request,result.TotalCount,result.FilteredCount, finaldata);

            return new DataTablesJsonResult(response, true);
        }
```

When i debug script there is a postdata and it converts to Json. There is the data what i want. 
There is an image about network tab from browser.
[image: You can look in here]

When it comes to action. The datas are null.

I have configuration on my startup.

```
   services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

   services.RegisterDataTables();
```

Otherwise when i try to Ajax Get without anything. Like this. It is working.

```
ajax: "@Url.Action("TableDatas", "Admin")",
```

But i wanna make post calls because i have custom filters. I need to send extrathings.
I tried [FromBody] etc...

I am missing something but what i dont know.

Comment: Could you share more details that could reproduce your issue?For using filter in datatables,you could refer to:https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnServerParams

Comment: @andreas I did it before. For my .net project. It worked well.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed the fact that you're using `DataTables` and its [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) property. This one accepts a `function` for [`data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data)

Comment: @Rena I am using last version of Datatable. The site you have given for DataTables v1.9 and earlier.